# Pandas calculate np.var() for each column

Tags: python, pandas

How to calculate np.var() for each column? If np.var()<0.1,  then remove the column.

```
Id  F   M   R
7   1   286 907
12  1   286 907
17  1   186 1271
21  1   296 905
30  1   308 908
32  1   267 905
40  2   591 788
41  1   486 874
47  1   686 906
74  1   230 907
```

Comment: Can you post your script plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [62]: df[df.columns[(df.var(ddof=0) >= 1.0)]]
Out[62]:
   Id    M     R
0   7  286   907
1  12  286   907
2  17  186  1271
3  21  296   905
4  30  308   908
5  32  267   905
6  40  591   788
7  41  486   874
8  47  686   906
9  74  230   907
```

Explanation:

```
In [64]: (df.var(ddof=0) >= 1.0)
Out[64]:
Id     True
F     False
M      True
R      True
dtype: bool


In [61]: df.columns[(df.var(ddof=0) >= 1.0)]
Out[61]: Index(['Id', 'M', 'R'], dtype='object')

In [62]: df[df.columns[(df.var(ddof=0) >= 1.0)]]
Out[62]:
   Id    M     R
0   7  286   907
1  12  286   907
2  17  186  1271
3  21  296   905
4  30  308   908
5  32  267   905
6  40  591   788
7  41  486   874
8  47  686   906
9  74  230   907
```

PS thanks to @ayhan - he has noticed that [pandas's var()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) uses default value for the `ddof=1` parameter and [numpy's implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) uses `ddof=0` per default.

Comment: For the exact equivalent of np.var, you need to pass `ddof=0` to pandas var. By default, pandas calculates the sample variance as opposed to population variance.